# Как понять написание кода в внутри preg_march_all?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

В preg_match_all первым аргументом вставляется html блок

в таком виде он у меня

```
$regex = '#<div class="width100 floatleft center">(.+?)</div>#mis';
```

Как понять какие символы писать чтоб внутри получить тег h2  и img c изменением src?

Comment: Лучше напишите исходную строку, и результирующую строку (которую нужно получить из исходной). В текущем варианте вашего вопроса невозможно понять, что же вам требуется в итоге.

Comment: есть такой [сайт](https://regex101.com), который рассказывает что означает регулярка, а также позволяет проверить её на некоторых значениях